# get client_id from foursquare by OAuth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, foursquare

I am trying to get a user venue history from foursquare. I know first of all a user should access to my application. I am using OAuth2 gem. How can I get client_id of the user?

```
cli = OAuth2::Client.new('CLIENT_ID', :authorize_url => "/oauth2/authorize", :token_url => "/oauth2/access_token", :site => 'https://foursquare.com')
```

ok, I am just editing my question. I understood why client_id has to be used (thanks to Martin and umesh awasthi). I am asking about why I can't get token of a user? my whole code is;

```
cli = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, :authorize_url => "/oauth2/authorize", :token_url => "/oauth2/access_token", :site => 'https://foursquare.com')
cli.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000")
token = cli.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/person/index")
response = token.get('api/resource', :params => {'query_foo' => 'bar'})
response.class.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer of `Martin` client id is a unique id associated with your application.All OAuth service provider need this client id to identity yourself.

I suggest you to first go through some basic understanding of OAuth as this protocol work on 2 major things

```
 1. Client_id: this is a unique id assigned to your application you
    create on any Oauth service provider or when you register you application.

 2. Secret_key:This is another part of Oauth communication which use to 
    Authenticate the  consumer i.e you application.
```

Though some Oauth system like Google provides Anonymous calling but that never being encouraged at all.

So whatever OAuth service you are using, you need to register your application with them and get `client_key` and `secret` which should be the part of every communication you making with OAuth

here is the quick steps taken from forsquare website

```
Redirect users who wish to authenticate to

https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
    ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
```

If a user accepts, they will be redirected back to

```
https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE
```

once user authorize you OAuth will redirect back with the code which you need to pass them again to get access token

```
  Your server will make a request for

https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
&code=CODE
```

The response will be JSON

```
{ access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }
```

Save this access token for this user in your database.Hope this swill help you

Comment: thank you Umesh Awasthai. I used this solution and it helped me very much.

Answer (score 0):

The client_id is the client_id for your application, which you get when you register an app [here](https://foursquare.com/oauth/). It is not associated with a particular user, but with your application.

Comment: yes I realized that I asked wrong question. The correct question is; when I use that code (at the above) I can't get the user token. How can I get access_token of a user whose email address I send to foursquare?

Comment: @yagmurdursun once you get authorization token you need to pass this authorization token to get the Access token.

Comment: As I've said before, you can't do this using email adresses. It just isn't possible.